# Using get() to write a dictionary function more concisely

Tags: python

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1

    return d

print(histogram('brontosaurus'))
```

So I am asked to use 'get' method to write the function more concisely. It says I should be able to remove the 'if' statement. I tried different things but I just need to see an example before I understand... Please provide example code thank you very much!

Update: I have researched it, I understand 'what' get is but I am having trouble using it in this case. I don't know how to modify this function... This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: do some google search you will find lot of examples

Comment: "python dict get" in google returns quite a lot of docs, tutorials and examples.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am trying to learn an example out of the book I am reading. Please don't say ignorant things like that.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `dict.get(k,v)` will search the dictionary for the key `k` and return it. However, if `k` does not exist in the dictionary, instead of raising a `KeyError` like `d[k]` does and potentially crashing the program, it will instead return the default value provided, `v`. Calling `get(k)` without specifying a default value `v` will return `None`.

With this said, it's a trivial matter to remove the `if` statement:

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        d[c] = d.get(c,0) + 1
    return d
```

If `d[c]` does not exist, `d.get(c,0)` will in turn return `0`, the provided default value. If `d[c]` does exist, `d.get(c,0)` will return the stored value. Therefore, if a key is not yet in the dictionary, `d[c]` is set to `0 + 1` which is, of course, 1. The next time that particular key is `get`-ed, `get` will return the stored value `1` instead, then add 1 and reassign, and so on.

Comment: Thanks that is nice of you to explain it that helps a lot!

Comment: @Spencer Happy to help. Don't forget, accept answer, etc